# wso2 apimanager external api publish and subscribe example

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Need a good example for publishing and subscribing an external api(running in my local) with URL(like http://localhost:8080/devices/{deviceId} where deviceId is a string) in WSO2 API manager.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: it's a little unclear what do you want to achieve. You want to expose an API with resource /devices/{deviceId}, ok.. and what do you have with?

Comment: For example : If hello World program is running in my local, I need to know how to publish, subscribe and invoke this service through API Manager. Thanks for your response

Answer (score 0):

It is all in the documentation - [API Manager Quick Start](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Quick+Start+Guide)

Comment: I am getting "error": "no response from server" as response when I try to invoke the api from api manager. (The server is running)

Comment: I assume you are trying to use API Store console and the certificate is not trusted. try to open https://localhost:8243/ in a new window and allow using the arbitrary certificate so the store client will the certificate (the address should be as well visible from the store in the curl command)

Comment: An example - https://medium.com/@malintha/exposing-a-simple-rest-api-using-wso2-api-manager-590a629d8ba0